# problem to use plasma-nm on xubuntu 16.04 (Solved)

Tags: networking, hot-spot

I used to install and setup hotspot that support android phones using the  plasma-nm package but in this fresh installation of xubuntu 16.04 it's not working each time i try to setup the hotspot it says failed to create the connection

the exact error message is :

```
Failed to add connection RRR
Connector.gateway-ping-timeout can not set property: 
value"35730608" of type  guint is invalid or out of range for property
"gateway-ping-timeout" of type guint
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple . i didn't need to install any thing to create an acces point supported by android phones . i used the stock network to create hotspot  and it's working . so it seems it's now embedded in the system and no need to install another package